# How to create differential column and select the entry with the maximal diff MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have small db which consist of the following tables:

```
  describe cast;
  +----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | actor_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | movie_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | salary   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  +----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

   describe movies;
  +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
  | title | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | year  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | genre | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And I'm trying to find which actor had the longest "pause" between two films.

I have tried to follow this logic:
   
(1) Create a table which consist of the actors_id and films years
   
(2) Order the above table by actor name and then year
   
(3) Create a new column of the diff between every 
     sequential years
   
(4) For every actor_id find the maximal diff
   
(5) Select the actor_id with the maximal diff

to do so I have first joined between the cast and movies table to get a table from the following format:

```
  actor_id | year
  ---------------
    11111 | 2000
    11111 | 2015
    22222 | 2001
    22222 | 2005
```

Using:

```
  select cast.actor_id, movies.year
  from movies 
  right join 
  cast on cast.movie_id = movies.id                                                                         
                order by actor_id,  movies.id
```

then I have tried to create a diff column using:

```
 select x.actor_id,
        x.year,
        x.year - coalesce(max(y.year), x.year) diff
 from (select cast.actor_id, movies.year
                from movies 
                right join cast on cast.movie_id = movies.id                                                                        
                order by actor_id) x
 left 
 join (select cast.actor_id, movies.year
                from movies 
                right join cast on cast.movie_id = movies.id                                                                        
                order by actor_id) y
 on y.year < x.year
 group by x.actor_id
```

However i cannot group by the actor_id, getting the following Error:

```
Error Code: 1055. 
Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
nonaggregated column 'x.year' which is not functionally dependent on
columns in GROUP BY clause;
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm new to SQL and probably over-complicate things, can you give guide-lines to how you would solve this problem?

Comment: I think I just did